# How to print datatables with pictures on a record?

Tags: printing, datatables

I want to retrieve my datatables, but when I print images my datatables don't appear.
any one can help?

[image: My data tables]
[image: Print result]

do you have alternative, or solution for this problem?

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#tabeldata').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
            columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
         },
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body)
                        .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
                        .prepend(
                            '<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
                        );

                    $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                        .addClass( 'compact' )
                        .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                }
            }
        ]
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace your `exportOptions` as under:

```html
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('#tabeldata').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {stripHtml: false },
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body)
                        .css( 'font-size', '10pt' );
            /*            .prepend(
                            '<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'    
                        ); */

                    $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                        .addClass( 'compact' )
                        .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    })
</script>
```